# Xamarin.iOS - Memory leak issue UIImage/UIImageView

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have added Controller to my app which adjusts image Brightness and Contrast using UISlider. My app crashes when I move slider many times and I think it is causing memory leak but I am unable to find where it is happening and how to fix it since I've never done it before.

```
public abstract class FilteringDemoDelegate
{
 public abstract void ImageViewControllerDidFinish(UIImage filteredImage);
}

public class ImageViewController : UIViewController
{
   UIImage sourceImage, displayImage, resultImage;   
   public FilteringDemoDelegate filteringDelegate;
   UIButton saveButton, resetButton;
   UIImageView imageView;
   UISlider sliderC, sliderB;        
   UILabel labelC, labelB;

public ImageViewController(UIImage image)
{            
        sourceImage = image;
}

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    Title = "Settings";
    View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;            

    resetButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
    resetButton.Frame = new CGRect(110, 40, 90, 40);
    resetButton.SetTitle("Reset", UIControlState.Normal);
    resetButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.FromRGB(11, 132, 66), UIControlState.Normal);

    resetButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {              
        sliderB.Value = 0;
        sliderC.Value = 1;     
        HandleValueChanged(sender, e);
    };
    View.Add(resetButton);

    saveButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
    saveButton.Frame = new CGRect(210, 40, 90, 40);
    saveButton.SetTitle("Save", UIControlState.Normal);
    saveButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.FromRGB(11, 132, 66), UIControlState.Normal);
    saveButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        if (resultImage != null)
        {
            ImageEditingViewController(resultImage);
        }
        else
        {
            ImageEditingViewController(sourceImage);
        }                
    };
    View.Add(saveButton);

    labelC = new UILabel(new CGRect(10, 100, 90, 20));          
    labelB = new UILabel(new CGRect(10, 140, 90, 20));

    labelC.Text = "Contrast";           
    labelB.Text = "Brightness"; 

    View.Add(labelC);           
    View.Add(labelB);

    sliderC = new UISlider(new CGRect(100, 100, 210, 20));       
    sliderB = new UISlider(new CGRect(100, 140, 210, 20));

    sliderC.MinValue = 0;
    sliderC.MaxValue = 4;
    sliderC.Value = 1;

    sliderB.MinValue = -1;
    sliderB.MaxValue = 1;
    sliderB.Value = 0;           

    // update the image in 'real time' as the sliders are moved
    sliderC.ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;     
    sliderB.ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;

    View.Add(sliderC);           
    View.Add(sliderB);

    imageView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(10, 200, View.Bounds.Width - 20, View.Bounds.Height - 200));            
    displayImage = sourceImage;
    imageView.Image = displayImage;
    View.Add(imageView);            
}

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   // use the low-res version
    imageView.Image = AdjustImage(displayImage);
    if (resultImage != null)
    {
        resultImage.Dispose();
    }                       
    resultImage = imageView.Image;
}

CIContext context;
CIColorControls colorCtrls; //CIFilter

UIImage AdjustImage(UIImage image)
{           
        if (colorCtrls == null)
            colorCtrls = new CIColorControls() { Image = CIImage.FromCGImage(image.CGImage) };
        else
            colorCtrls.Image = CIImage.FromCGImage(image.CGImage);

        if (context == null)
            context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);

        colorCtrls.Contrast = (float)Math.Round(sliderC.Value, 1);
        colorCtrls.Brightness = (float)Math.Round(sliderB.Value, 1);            

      using (var outputImage = colorCtrls.OutputImage)
        {
            var result = context.CreateCGImage(outputImage, outputImage.Extent);
            return UIImage.FromImage(result);
        }       

}

public void ImageEditingViewController(UIImage filteredImage)
{
    if (filteringDelegate != null)
    {
        filteringDelegate.ImageViewControllerDidFinish(filteredImage);
    }
    DismissViewController(false, null);           
}
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach the detailed error message? BTW, you can try [profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=vsmac) to  debug your app.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT '2018-06-04 08:33:17.002 MobileApp.UI.iOS[19733:5710577] Got memory pressure notification (non-critical)
2018-06-04 08:33:22.527 MobileApp.UI.iOS[19733:5710577] Got memory pressure notification (critical)
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #11
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #16
The thread 0xb has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The app has been terminated.
Failed to Stop app:  An error occured on client IDB490753 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.9.0.753/stop-app
The app has been terminated.'

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT It says that profiler can be on VS Enterprise only, I use VS professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting 'slider.Continuous = false' salved the issue, which displays image based on last value of the slider instead of storing each value change.